# Assignment of matrix through nested loops only works for first row

Tags: python, numpy

See the following simplified code

```
import numpy as np
u=np.zeros((3,3))
i,j=0,0
while i<3:
    while j<3:
        u[i,j]=i+j
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

I was expecting a full matrix u (except for [0,0] element). This code seems to assign to only first row of u. I have used something like this in MATLAB in the past with success

Comment: `np.arange(3)[:,None]+np.arange(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you forgot to reset the index `j` when the inner loop is complete. After the first row, j will be greater than 3 so `u[i, j]` will not make sense.
The correct code would be:

```
import numpy as np
u=np.zeros((3,3))
i=0
while i<3:
    j=0
    while j<3:
        u[i,j]=i+j
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

This should fix your issue and initialize `u` to the following array:

```
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [2. 3. 4.]]
```

Note that although the code is correct, it could be rewritten to be a bit cleaner using for loops and ranges:

```
import numpy as np
u = np.zeros((3, 3))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        u[i, j] = i+j
```

Comment: There is however no point in using numpy if you loop over the indices. Use vectorial code `u = np.arange(3)[:, None] + np.arange(3)`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you do not reset `j` before entering the second loop. The first time the inner loop completes, we have `j=3` hence we never enter the inner loop after the first time. To fix, simply add `j=0` before entering the second loop.